# What would be the space complexity of the following recursive function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, space-complexity

A recursive function which initializes an empty 2D vector which takes up n^2 space, along with n stack space.

```
void s (int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return;
    // n^2 space
    vector<vector<int>> a(n, vector<int>(n));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
         a[i][j] = i * j;
    s(n-1);
}
```

Comment: `a` is unused and construction of an `int` has no visible side effects , so any decent compiler would discard `a` entirely.

Comment: Since calling `s` has no observable behavior, the space and time complexity of the algorithm can be argued to be `O(0)` because it can in theory be optimized out. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Lets not consider any compiler optimizations, and I have added a nested loop, so that `S` has some observable behavior now. What would be the space complexity now?

Answer (score 0):

It goes like  n^2 + (n-1)^2 + ... + 1^2 .
The result will be n * (n+1) * (2n+1) / 6 = O(n^3).
But since in reality they are all 0 pages, it will not take that much space.

Comment: Shouldn't we consider the stack space also? Stack size will go upto n, before the function hitting the base condition of n == 0, so should it be something like :
n^2 + (n-1)^2 + ... + 1^2  + n (stack space) ?

Comment: Overall, the order of space complexity will be n^3.

Comment: If I remember my uni courses properly, you don't need to worry about lower-order components. O(N^2+N) is just O(N^2). Higher-order terms will always dominate for a "large enough" N, which is the point of such an analysis.